# If I add Gmail photo attachments to Google Drive > Google Photos folder, will they still count against my Drive quota?

Tags: gmail, google-drive, google-photos

I am approaching my Google Drive limit, and Gmail uses 8GB. I found some photos with large attachments via filtering by size.

If I add these photos to Google Drive > Google Photos, will they stop counting against my quota?

Answer (score 1):

Your storage space [is shared](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/6374270) between Drive, Gmail and Photos anyway, so in general it doesn't matter which of them contains those pictures.

But if you upload via Google Photos' webpage and/or use Google Photos/Drive's sync app (it's now the same app for both of them), **and** choose [(only) High Quality](https://support.google.com/photos/answer/6314648), that reduced quality will entitle you to **unlimited** image storage.